# Can a light with a built in motion sensor, be used with dimmer switch?

Tags: lighting, dimmer-switch, motion-sensor

My front lights are bright and have built in motion sensors.  I would like the capability to dim these lights.  So my question is, can I use a dimmer switch on these lights (with built in motion sensors) without adversely affecting the motion sensor function.

Here's an example of the light switch I was thinking of using: [Lutron Diva 1.25-Amp White Preset Dimmer](http://www.lowes.com/pd_160613-539-DVWCL-153PH-WH_0__?productId=3736413&Ntt=dimmer%20switch&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Ddimmer%2Bswitch&facetInfo=)

Answer (score 2):

No, such an arrangement will either flat out not work, or have very poor reliability.

The motion detector logic requires full uninterrupted voltage and a dimmer switch is going to inject noise into the power which will disrupt the motion logic or its sensor.

Additionally, even if the motion sensor continued to work, the cycling of the light on and off would disrupt the load of the dimmer and make the voltage wildly vary.

You might get lucky with some quality components and dimmer settings, but it would be better to simply replace the bulbs with those of a lower wattage.